# undefined method `contains_text' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, watir

I use Watir in RadRails IDE. I create a class which checks if some text is present on my web page:

```
class Text

  def initialize(text, object)
    @text   = text
    @object = object

    if $ie.contains_text(@text)
      puts "Test for" + @object + "failed"
      puts $ie.link(:text => /Exception:/)

      h = $ie.link(:text => /Exception:/)
      r.addtoReport(testReport, "check" + @object, "FAILED", h.text)
    else
      puts("Test for" + @object + "passed")

      r.addtoReport(
          testReport, 
          "check" + @object, 
          "PASSED", 
          "Test for" + @object + "passed"
      )
    end
  end

end
```

But when I try to execute the code in my test I get the following error -

```
BPM/Company.rb:38:in `initialize': undefined method `contains_text' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from BPM/Company.rb:79:in `new'
from BPM/Company.rb:79:in `<main>'
```

I call the class by this command -

```
Text.new("Menu", "login")
```

Changes in code -

```
def initialize(text, object, ie)
    @text   = text
    @object = object
    @ie=ie
    if @ie.contains_text(@text)
      puts "Test for" + @object + "failed"
      puts @ie.link(:text => /Exception:/)
```

I call the class by this command -

```
Text_pos.new("Terms", "login",$ie)
```

Before describing classes ie is initialized `ie=Watir::IE.new`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is $ie coming from? -- it seems you didn't initialize ie:

```
ie = Watir::IE.new
```

Comment: i have changed  code a bit and grt same error, changes is in updated question